# Crossfade images with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I'm trying to accomplish a crossfade effect for my banner images on my homepage. I'm doing this with jQuery and the fading effect is working fine. 
This is my  code:

```
<script>
 function bannerImages(){
  var $active = $('.banner-test .banner_one');
  var $next = ($active.next().length > 0) ? $active.next() : 
 $('.banner-test img:first');
  $next.css('z-index',2);//move the next image up the pile
  $active.fadeOut(1500,function(){//fade out the top image
  $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');//reset the z-index and unhide the image
      $next.css('z-index',3).addClass('active');//make the next image the top one
  });
}

  $(document).ready(function(){
    // run every 7s
   setInterval('cycleImages()', 7000);
  })
</script>
```

As I said this is working fine however I've got one issue.  In order for this to work I need to apply `position:absolute` to the `.banner-test img` class. Now I've also got another div within the `.banner-test` class to display some text on top of the banner image. 
The code looks like this :

```
 <div class="banner-test">
        <img class="banner_one" src="../image.jpg" alt="" />
         <img src="../image2.jpg" alt=""/>

        <div id="text">
            <p class="text1">Sample Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the css for the `#text` :

```
 #text {
position:absolute; 
bottom:35px ;  
left:10px;  
width:70% ;   
background-color:#104E8B;  
font-size:1em;  
color:white;  
opacity:0.95; 
filter:alpha(opacity=95); /* IE transparency */  
}
.text1 {
padding:13px;  
margin:0px;  
}
.banner-test {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```

So if I apply absolute positioning to the image it messes up the layout with the text (everything is pushed to the top of the page).
Can anybody think of a workaround for this?

**EDIT**

https://jsfiddle.net/ztrez888/1/embedded/result/ this is the fiddle - if position absolute is applied to the `.banner-test img` the text disappears

Comment: To be able to help we would really need to see a working example. Could you setup a http://jsfiddle.net showing the problem?

Comment: YOu have to set the height for the `.banner-test` class parent div.

Comment: only one of the two images needs absolute position, so you can pile them ;)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan see edit

Answer (score 0):

You said: *(everything is pushed to the top of the page)*

Its because your wrapper element `.banner-test` doesn't have a static height set. so when you apply a absolute position to the images in it *`.banner-test`* get shrink to height of the `#text .text1`.

Either set a height in the css:

```
.banner-test {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height:200px; /* <--put the height of img */
}
```

or calculate it with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var arr = $('.banner-test img').map(function(){ // get the heights of imgs in array
                  return $(this).height();
             }).get(),
       h   = Math.max.apply(Math, arr); // find out the greatest height in it.

    $('.banner-test').css('height', h); // set the height here.
    // run every 7s
    setInterval('cycleImages()', 7000); // then cycle the images.
});
```

<sub>`cycleImages()` is been called in the setInterval and you have `bannerImages()` function on the page. I am assuming you have this `cycleImages()` function.</sub>

---

### Updates:

```
  #text {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #104E8B;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: white;
    opacity: 0.95;
    filter: alpha(opacity=95);
    /* IE transparency */
    z-index: 5;  /* <----change these here*/
    left: 10%;
    top: 0;
  }
```

#### [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ztrez888/3/)

Comment: It's working with the height set- only issue with that is that I have been setting height/width with percentage instead of pixel and it seems not to be working when I do this

Comment: @MariaL i repeat myself :) , just set one image in absolute position , check my css example in comment .if both image same size, then the one remaining in the flux will size header ;)

Comment: @MariaL check the udpated fiddle.

Comment: i believe t is morelike http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GoqNYe  if i followed its fiddle. css animation is there for a quick demo instead firing jquery ;)